# Как получить данные из Firebase без дочерних элементов?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Я получаю данные из Firebase (realtime):

```
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<FbCafeMenu> cafeList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                FbCafeMenu fcm = snapshot.getValue(FbCafeMenu.class);
                fcm.setIndex(snapshot.getKey());
                cafeList.add(fcm);
            }

            SelectCafeActivity.this.cafeList.addAll(cafeList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("FIREBASE", "Fail read: " + databaseError.getMessage()
                    + "\n" + databaseError.getDetails());
        }
    });
```

Проблема в том, что база очень большая и многослойная, а в конечном счете я выбираю только 1 ветку.
**Как можно получить из `Firebase` все данные для определенного уровня?**
Для примера:
БД:

```
    ГлавныйЭлемент1:
        Категория11:
            Элемент111;
            Элемент112;
            Элемент113;
        Категория12:
            Элемент121;
            Элемент122;
    ГлавныйЭлемент2:
        Категория21:
            Элемент211;
            Элемент212;
```

Мне нужно получить только ГлавныеЭлементы

Comment: Что значит без дочерних? Это firestore или realtime-database? В любом случае через запросы https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Realtume-database. Спасибо что уточнили.

Comment: @Jorik, насколько помню, такое сделать нельзя. Вот если бы вы использовали firestore, то другое дело.